How to keep UI unblocked while processing in WPF C#
I've read many examples about threads and asynchronous..., but I can't make the UI in wpf c# not freeze when calculating files on a disk - I can't move the window..., I have to wait that the counting process ends.
Once the counting is finished, control of the user interface is resumed.
My button code and the counting result in a texbox
    public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d)
{

    long size = 0;
    FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
        try
        {
            {
                size += fi.Length;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

   private async void Save_bkp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
       Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {

           TextBox_Dimensioni.Text = Convert.ToString((double)DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(CopiaFoto)));

       }));
   });

  }

If I don't put Dispatcher.Invoke I get the error: The calling thread cannot access this object because this object is owned by another thread.
I've tried many ways but nothing always freezes...

have you tried to use BackgroundWorker as described here ?

Stephen Cleary Blog: Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker: Conclusion

And you should also use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles (and not GetFiles). In your case GetFiles results in two complete iterations, one to get all files and the second to inspect each one to obtain the size.

And perhaps write the DirInfo method as return d.EnumerateFiles().Select(f => f.Length).Sum();

Run the long running part inside of a task and await it. Then update the controls with the result.
This will take care to return to the initial synchronization context (in this case: the UI thread).
private async void Save_bkp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var size = await Task.Run( () => DirSize( new DirectoryInfo(CopiaFoto) ) );
    TextBox_Dimensioni.Text = size.ToString();
}

